# Using LD to link intermediate files

Tags: c++, linker, ld

If I have a.o, b.o, and c.o, how do I make ld link them into d.o, which is then linked into my main object file? All that I want to have happen is that all the symbols in the input files get combined into one big output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concatenation of .o files is called a library. You create one 
with the **ar** library utility:

```
ar rvs mylib.a a.o b.o c.o
```

You can then link against the library:

```
cc main.c mylib.a
```

Answer (score 3):

Found it. The -r option links files incrementally, so they can be used as input to ld.